# Show scroll button with time-delay

Tags: jquery, scroll, timeout, hide, show

I have a div which on scroll, will show a button. I want this button to only show for 2 seconds after the last scroll. There is a glitch in my script which I can't figure out. Sometimes it shows for 2 seconds, sometimes less, sometimes it hides instantly.

The problem I think is that it only counts from the first scroll, and each scroll afterwards does not reset this timer until it expires. If the timer expires then the scroll shows again.

```
$("#layout-main").live('scroll',function(){
 $("#main-totop").show();
});
$("#main-totop").live('click',function(){
 mainapi.scrollTo(0,0);
 setTimeout(function(){
  $('#main-totop').hide();
 }, 2000); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
$("#layout-main").live('scroll',function(){
    $("#main-totop").stop().show(0).delay(2000).hide(0);
});
$("#main-totop").live('click',function(){
    mainapi.scrollTo(0,0);
    $('#main-totop').hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what's different and why?

Comment: it doesn't. There's nothing there to show that we need it to hide 2 seconds after scroll. the delay needs to be worked into the #layout-main event.

Comment: I've adjusted the code to fit your desription.
By passing 1 to `.hide` it does run as animation and we can use jQueries `.delay` instead of a timeout.

Comment: Yes. It only affects the chain of animations on an element. Thats why `hide(0)` would not wait for the delay, as its not internally treated as an animation and just toggles the elements `display` value.

Comment: hide() does not wait, hide(0) respects the delay(). Seems like as long as there is a value passed, it treats the toggle as an animation.

Comment: Good to know! `hide(0)` would be the better choice, then. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `.promise().done()` and i suggest you to use `.on()` because `.live()` is `been removed in jQuery version 1.9.0+`

```
$("#layout-main").on('click', '#main-totop', function(){
   mainapi.scrollTo(0,0).promise().done(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           $(this).hide();
       }, 2000);
   });
});
```

or you can try as this:

```
$("#layout-main").on('click', '#main-totop', function(){
   mainapi.scrollTo(0,0).promise().done(function(){
      $(this).delay(2000).hide();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not represent what you describe.

It says: when you scroll on **#layout-main** the **#main-totop** element shows.
If clicked then scrolls to top and after 2 seconds hides.

From your description you want the button (probably **#main-totop**) appears only for 2 seconds after the last scroll and then hide.

If i am right then you need something like this:

```
var mytimer;
$("#layout-main").live('scroll',function(){
    clearTimeout(mytimer);
    $('#main-totop').show();
    mytimer = setTimeout(function(){
      $('#main-totop').hide();
    }, 2000); 
});
$("#main-totop").live('click',function(){
 mainapi.scrollTo(0,0);
});
```